# Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where all points in the graph of f cannot be approximated by other points in $f$?

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Does there exist an explicit function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such if $X$ is the graph of $f$ (i.e., $X=\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$) then for each point $p$ on the graph of $f$, I want to find some $\varepsilon$-ball around $p$ whose intersection with the graph of $f$ is precisely $\left\{p\right\}$

**Attempt:**

<s>Does the [conway base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) answer the question?</s>

**Edit:** I assume the statement is false but I don't know how to prove this. It seems there has to be at least one sequence $(x_r)$ of real numbers, where as $x_r\to x$, we get  $f(x)\to f(x_r)$, but I don't know how to proceed. Any tips would be nice.

Comment: Please tell me this makes sense.

Comment: Please show the attempt to prove the statement

Comment: @Sgg8 I'm not sure how to prove the statement, but let me try an explanation.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this. What is $V$, and why do you not mention it again? It seems to me that for each point $p$ on the graph of $f$, you want to find some $\epsilon$-ball around $p$ whose intersection with the graph of $f$ is precisely $\{ p \}$? Is that right?

Comment: @Lewis Yes, that is correct.

Comment: What is the relevance of the metric space $(V, d)$?

Comment: @Lewis I wasn't sure whether $X$ and $V$ should be different. If so, then $X$ should be a subset of $V$.

Comment: You have a function from the reals to the reals.  Why do you need any other metric space, and why would you use $X$ for both some mentioned metric space which is never seen nor alluded to again after the first sentence, and for the graph of $f$?

Comment: $f(x)$ with $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, I thing is an example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I assumed if I mentioned $d$, I have to refer to a metric space.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I got rid of it, hopefully everything is clear now.

Comment: But you never mentioned $d$! And the reals already have a metric. It's like saying "Let $X$ represent a country on Earth. Is there a way to get from 2nd avenue in Manhattan to 3rd avenue in Manhattan?"

Comment: @Piquito certainly not. Ever ball around a point in the graph includes lots of other points in the graph.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, you have to  look at my previous edits to understand how I mentioned $d$. I apologize for my stupidity.

Comment: Interesting question (despite the issues with its formulation). I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347133/do-these-hyper-discontinuous-functions-exist) should answer it.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}^n$ with usual topology has no uncountable discrete subset

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Precisaly for what you say, the example i got is good. Well, maybe my English goes against my understanding of problem.

Comment: @Piquito Yes, it seems that you're not understanding the problem. The OP is asking for a graph where every point is isolated.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If proving that a no hyper-continuous $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the same as proving no hyper-continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ exists, then the linked post answers my question.

Comment: Any such function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ restricts to one on $[0,1]$. And essentially the problem is that a discrete uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would allow you to find an injection from that set to $\mathbb{Q}^2$, which is patently impossible.